# Issues having a class return a Fraction as a decimal in C++

Tags: c++, class, fractions

I am somewhat new to C++ (I have been learning it for a few months now on and off), and am attempting to make a Calculator application. I have a pretty good understanding of how the language works as I have learned through a guide.

I use a class for Fractions - with my member variables under private and functions (set, get, etc) under public. The issue I am having is with one of my functions - the purpose is basically to return the decimal form of said Fraction. I can do the math directly in Main and it would work great, by always outputting the decimals even without use of setprecision.

Yet, whenever I use the same math inside of the class function - it always posts the number one.

I may be making a mistake somewhere, but I cannot seem to find it and was hoping you fine people could lend a hand :D

Here is my main CPP file

```
//
//  main.cpp
//  Calculator
//
//  Created by Bryan Douglas on 2017-03-30.
//  Copyright (c) 2017 Bryan Douglas. All rights reserved.
//

#include "Fraction.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Fraction fiftyoverhundred(50, 100);

    std::cout << "The decimal of the fraction you have entered is " << fiftyoverhundred.getDecimal() << std::endl;
}
```

Here is my Fraction Header file

```
//
//  Fraction.h
//  Calculator
//
//  Created by Bryan Douglas on 2017-03-30.
//  Copyright (c) 2017 Bryan Douglas. All rights reserved.
//

#ifndef Calculator_Fraction_h
#define Calculator_Fraction_h

class Fraction {
private:
    float m_numerator = 0;
    float m_denominator = 0;

public:
    Fraction(int numerator, int denominator);
    ~Fraction();

    void setNumerator(int NumeratorInput) { m_numerator = NumeratorInput;};
    int getNumerator() { return m_numerator;};
    void setDenominator(int DenominatorInput) { m_denominator = DenominatorInput;};
    int getDenominator() { return m_denominator;};

    float getDecimal() {return (float)m_numerator /  (float)m_numerator;};
};

#endif
```

Finally, here is my Fraction CPP file

```
//
//  Fraction.cpp
//  Calculator
//
//  Created by Bryan Douglas on 2017-03-30.
//  Copyright (c) 2017 Bryan Douglas. All rights reserved.
//

#include "Fraction.h"

#include <stdio.h>

Fraction::Fraction(int numerator, int denominator)
{
    m_numerator = numerator;
    m_denominator = denominator;
}

Fraction::~Fraction()
{

}
```

I know my coding standards and terms may be a little less than professional, but I like to fix those once the function is tested and is working as planned.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Check your calculation in `getDecimal`.

Comment: It seems the problem is a simple typo in your function that calculates the division.

Comment: Your code is chaotic. You store numerator and denominator as floats, and then cast them... I guess the source of your error is similar. You should read the code again and make sure you understand what's in there. Maybe you typed too fast.

Comment: My bad, I just noticed now. After I fixed it, everything worked great

Thanks for pointing my mistake out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your `getDecimal`:

```
float getDecimal() { return (float)m_numerator / (float)m_numerator; };
```

It doesn't make much sense to divide numerator by numerator. Change to:

```
...
float getDecimal() { return (float)m_numerator / (float)m_denominator; };
....
```

And your output will be as expected:

```
The decimal of the fraction you have entered is 0.5
```

Comment: Oh my god.... AHAHA, That would do it.

Lets write this one off as human error. I likely copied and pasted it and forgot to amend it to reflect the proper member.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @BryanDouglas Note that there is no need for the cast `(float)` since both variables are already declared as `float`.

Comment: Yes, I removed those as well when I tried your solution.

I figured, if I was making a mistake related to casting... Casting all of them should tell me.

Thanks again!

Comment: @BryanDouglas In general you should check compiler warnings, usually they are there for a reason. All these cast warnings should be fixed.

Comment: @Pavel When I compiled the code, I didn't receive any warnings nor errors.

The code seem to execute properly, I was just using the incorrect member.